# Are there any RoR projects exploring the use of web components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-component, native-web-component

This might not be an acceptable question for Stack Overflow but I didn't know where else to ask the question.

Web Components has been "about to happen" for a very long time.  It now appears that most browsers have most of the required pieces natively instead of using polyfills (which always worried me).

I'm wondering if Ruby On Rails is planing on moving to it or if there are any projects creating web components as well as Rails server code to take advantage of them.

Comment: Try asking this question on a discussion site like reddit. You're correct in that its not acceptable for SO as its purely speculative.

Comment: @max Ahh... reddit... that's a good idea.  I'll delete this tomorrow.  Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if Ruby On Rails is planing on moving to it or if there are any projects creating web components as well as Rails server code to take advantage of them.

The `webpacker` gem makes it easy to include some of the JS frameworks for non-native web components like Vue or React, but you can also use it with Polymer to support native web components. We do this at my work, and we don't necessarily use `webpacker` for it right now but I can assure you it's a very good gem.

Here's more info: https://github.com/rails/webpacker

Here's how you'd initiate a new rails project with webpacker set up for VueJS for instance:

```
rails new myapp --webpack=vue
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if rails is going to implement web-components as a built-in feature or not but the motive behind adding webpacker as default in rails 6 is to improve the integration of front-end/javascript libraries. So, you can use `vue-js`, `react-native` easily along with your rails app and build components in it.

I'm personally using many vue-js components in rails projects and having no issue with that.

P.S: Same as the question this might not be an acceptable answer :P